# Where can I share my benchmark results for elasticsearch php vendors

Tags: php, elasticsearch, benchmarking

I've benchmarked several elasticsearch php vendors, and I would like to share my experience!

I would write a simple topic on some blog (or something else) related to elasticsearch or php.

Could someone please advise me where I can post such info?

Answer (score 1):

Create a repository on Github and push your test setup and a php shell to run the benchmark. Don't forget to add a meaningful readm.md.

Oh and, give me the URL of the repo, I would like to run them as well. :) I'm pretty sure other people have an interest in this as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Medium" is quite nice for such purposes.

Comment: You can find benmark result here: https://medium.com/@cn007b/introduction-c47ed204f3c5